# How use localstack to test security group rules for an ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, localstack

I would like to use Localstack for quick testing of diff security group rules. For example, I want to create an ec2 instance, create an internet gateway, and then add a security group that allows ingress to the ec2 instance only on a specific port. I'd then test it by doing  a `curl` to the ec2 instance to see if I got the rule correct.

Is this possible with LocalStack?

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  access_key                  = "localstacktest"
  secret_key                  = "localstacktestkey"
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_requesting_account_id  = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true
  s3_use_path_style           = true

  endpoints {
    ec2           = "http://localhost:4566"
    iam           = "http://localhost:4566"
    s3            = "http://localhost:4566"
    glacier       = "http://localhost:4566"
    sns           = "http://localhost:4566"
    organizations = "http://localhost:4566"
  }
}

# ...elided...

resource "aws_security_group" "aws_ec2_sg" {
  name   = "aws_ec2_sg_allow_ssh"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.aws_ec2_vpc.id

  ingress {
    description = "Allow inbound ssh traffic"

    cidr_blocks = [var.cidr_block]
    from_port   = var.port
    protocol    = "tcp"
    to_port     = var.port
  }

  #...elided...
}

resource "aws_instance" "aws_ec2_instance" {
  ami                    = var.ami_id
  instance_type          = var.instance_type
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.aws_ec2_sg.id]

  tags = {
    name = var.ec2_name
  }
}
```

Is there a way to then make a `curl` call and have it return "ok", but if I change up the security group, to have to then fail due to security restrictions?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. As explained [here](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/1996), localstack in itself does not actually create any resources which you can login into or ping. It just mocks them.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for the reply. I don't need to be able to login to anything, I just need to see if ports are opened/closed based on the SG